# Brace expansion - too many expressions

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to find all files of the type FileName_trojan.sh, FileName_virus.sh, FileName_worm.sh. If any such file is found, then display a message.

Here FileName is the argument passed to a script.

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
if [ -e "$file""_"{trojan,virus,worm}".sh" ]
then
echo 'malware detected'
```

I tried to use brace expansion, but it did not work. I get the error "too many arguments"
How do I fix it ? Can I do it only with OR conditions ?

Also, this does not work -

```
-e "$file""_trojan.sh" -o "$file""_worm.sh" -o "$file""_virus.sh"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-e` operator can take only one argument; the brace expansion is expanded before passing arguments to the `-e`, so there are two extra arguments. You can use a loop:

```
for t in trojan virus worm; do
    if [ -e "{$file}_$t.sh" ]; then
        echo "malware detected"
    fi
do
```

or as Mark suggested before I could finish typing it:

```
for f in "${file}_"{trojan,virus,worm}.sh; do
    if [ -e "$f" ]; then
        echo "malware detected"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Or even `for f in "${file}"_{trojan,virus,worm}.sh; do if [ -e "$f" ]; then echo "malware detected"; fi; done`

Comment: Jinx. You owe me a coke :)

Comment: BTW, why do we have curly brackets in {$file}_$t.sh . Can't we use just $file. I tried it and i got an error.

Comment: `$file_$t.sh` will be interpreted as referring to the variable named "file_", which doesn't exist. The `{}` disambiguate where the variable name ends and plain text begins.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the expansion, it worked ok. The problem is with the `-e` test: it only takes one argument, not three.

Possible workaround:

```
i=0
for f in "$1"_{trojan,virus,worm}.sh ; do
    [ -e "$f" ] && (( i++ ))
done
if ((i)) ; then
    echo Malware detected.
fi
```